# node.js / Synchronize callsback in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in `node.js`, and as I understood any callback is creating a new event, which can be executed parallel.

for example, I have the next code with callback:

```
function testFunction(var1){
   s3.heah(var1, function(data, err){
      return err;
   })
}
```

and then I call to this function:

```
function callToOtherFunc(var1){
   var result = testFunction(var1);
   if (result != null){
      console.log("This is an error!");
   }
}
```

As I see, `result` is always `null`,  this because `s3.head` take some time to be returned, and the `callToOtherFunc` is continue with the execution.

How I can avoid it?

Comment: Source code of s3.heah would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the code too much, you need execute a callback in the callback of the `s3.heah` method like this:

```
function testFunction(var1, callback){
   s3.heah(var1, function(data, err){
      callback(err);
   });
}

function callToOtherFunc(var1){
   testFunction(var1, function(err) {
       if (result != null){
          console.log("This is an error!");
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `testFunction` return undefined, in this situation result will be undefined (`result == null`) at any time.

Rephrase previous answer you need to pass the `result` value to callback.

```
function testFunction(var1, callback){
   s3.heah(var1, function(data, err){
      callback(err, data);
   });
}

function callToOtherFunc(var1){
   testFunction(var1, function(err, result) {
       if (result != null){
          console.log("This is an error!");
       }
   }
}
```

To avoid this async hell use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

You need to change return value of functions to work with async:

```
function testFunction(var1, callback){
   var1 += 1;
   callback(null, var1);
}

function callToOtherFunc(err, result){
   if (result != null){
       console.log("This is an error!");
   }
}

var workflow = async.compose(testFunction, s3.heah),
    var1 = 10;
workflow(var1, callToOtherFunc);
```

It will works nice if you can change source of s3.heah to work with callback `function(err, data)` instead of `function(data, err)`, if it is not possible - don't include s3.heah in workflow.